# Invalid write of size 4

Tags: c, gcc, valgrind

On using valgrind, the following shows up:

```
==2639== Invalid write of size 4
==2639==    at 0x80499EC: sequencer_run (sequencer.c:253)
==2639==    by 0x804E176: thread_start (thread.c:105)
==2639==    by 0x8049072: main (genome.c:237)
==2639==  Address 0xbc1bc3ec is on thread 1's stack
==2639== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==2639==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xBC1BC3EC
==2639==    at 0x80499EC: sequencer_run (sequencer.c:253)
```

Relevant code:

```
sequencer.c:253  long threadId = thread_getId();

...

long thread_getId()
{
    return (long)(pthread_getspecific(global_threadId));// global_threadId is of type pthread_key_t
}
```

Also `global_threadId` is being created by:

```
pthread_key_create(&global_threadId, NULL);
```

and assigned the value using

```
pthread_setspecific(global_threadId, (long)threadId);//(threadId = 0 here)
```

Is the problem with the return type of `pthread_getspecific(void *)`. I tried modifying the code, but couldnt resolve the problem. Please help.

Comment: isn't pthread_key_t a typedef for uint32_t so this is no pointer? So shouldn't you be using `pthread_getspecific(&global_threadId)`

Comment: Is `thread_getId()` in same file? If another is it compiled with same compiler flags?

Comment: @ceedee, please consider providing a minimal working example reproducing the problem. Otherwise you pretty much are leaving people guessing as to what the problem could be. This, of course, greatly reduces your chances of getting help.

Comment: Had this been compiled with optimisation on?

Comment: Are all necessary headers in place? Does this compile without warning when all warnings are on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)?

Comment: @alk when i compile with these options, it shows just one warning:     warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code

Comment: @VladLazarenko Actually i am writing a code that uses another library. I am sorry but i cant think of simplifying it further without pasting the entire code. Pls let me know if u have any suggestion as to what additional info might be required..

Comment: Are you mixing 32bit and 64bit binaries (shared objects)?

Comment: @alk How do i find that?

Comment: @ceedee: You can use the `file` commnd to find out info on a file in general and if run against a shared object in particular also if it's for 32bit or 64bit.